# is there a simple way to port linux drivers to L4?

Tags: driver, linux-device-driver, microkernel, sel4

I want to build a system over seL4 and I do not want to write the drivers from scratch. I know that L4linux managaged to raise an entire linux kernel, drivers included, over fiasco.OC.

Ideally I want a driver wrapper that would allow me to run linux drivers as standalone tasks over sel4.

I am willing to code much. but I want to avoid reading hardware spec sheets and rewriting drivers.

Comment: Since seL4 is a microkernel and not monolithic like Linux, most of the drivers have to be ported explicitly as its IPC, memory, etc mechanisms are different.

Comment: Could somebody with 1500+ reputation create a tag "seL4", so it could be added here?  Seems there is some work in a seL4 specific Q/A site for stack overflow: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/120611/sel4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I last looked at L4 in depth many years ago.

Based on my understanding the answer to your question should be in general a no. The reasons for this are mainly in two aspects: For one is because a fully bloated linux driver needs to take care of too many aspects to integrate into the kernel subsystems. The another reason is the two kernels are different.

If the specific driver you are looking at does not heavily integrate into the kernel subsystems, it may be not a huge task for you to develop a wrapper.